# Is it possible to do a side by side install of ArcMap 10 & 10.1 using xp mode in windows 7?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, virtual-machine, hazus

My organization is running Arcgis 10.1 throughout the office. Staff currently is starting a project in which we need to use FEMA's HAZUS software. The problem is that HAZUS is only compatible with ArcGIS 10 SP 1&2. I was wondering if anyone here had attempted to do an install of 10.0 in Windows 7's xp mode virtualization. I have never used xp mode before and was wondering if it uses a separate drive partition from windows 7 or if this type of installation scenario is even possible.

If anyone has any experience with this type of scenario let me know how it went.

Comment: We use Oracle VirtualBox to have XP running ArcGIS 9 & 10 (sp1,sp2) as we have different clients with different versions of ArcGIS. All works without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you describe and everything will work fine. Windows XP Mode is a full-on virtual machine, running on a virtual hard drive contained in a file on the host computer. I have ArcGIS 9.3 installed in an XP Mode VM so that I can open some old projects that use the DSMapbook extension, and I've run ArcGIS 10.0 in XP mode. You can access the host machine's network shares while you're in the XP VM as well.

Licensing may be a slight problem, if you are using a license server, the XP VM machine will need to be set up so that it can see the license server.